# An abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ is a full subcategory of the bounded derived category $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I want to prove that  an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ is a full subcategory of the bounded derived category $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$. As the objects of $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$ consist only of bounded complexes over the abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ we can think an object $C \in \mathcal{C}$ as the following complex concentrated in zero:

$$...\to 0 \to 0 \to C \to 0 \to 0 \to 0$$.

So $Obj(\mathcal{C}) \subset Obj(D^{b}(\mathcal{C}))$. I need to prove that for every $C,D \in Obj(\mathcal{C}) \subset  Obj(D^{b}(\mathcal{C})) $ we got $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D)=Hom_{D^{b}(\mathcal{C})}(C,D)$. If $f \in Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D)$ we are suppose to see this morphism as

$$\begin{array}{c}
 ... & \xrightarrow{} & 0 & \xrightarrow{} & C & \xrightarrow{} & 0 & \xrightarrow{} & ... \\
 &  & \downarrow{}  & & \downarrow{f}  & & \downarrow{} & \\
... & \xrightarrow{} & 0 & \xrightarrow{} & D & \xrightarrow{} & 0& \xrightarrow{} & ... \\
\end{array}$$

where the morphism on the zero degree is  our $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Still dont see how this is a morphism of $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$. I understand $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$ from [https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.schapira/lectnotes/HomAl.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Epierre.schapira/lectnotes/HomAl.pdf) as taking the homotopy category of bounded complexes over $\mathcal{C}$, named $K^{b}(\mathcal{C})$ and then localizing with respect the quasi-isomorphisms on $K^{b}(\mathcal{C})$ to obtain $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$.  I believe what Im really supossed to prove is that $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D) \cong Hom_{D^{b}(\mathcal{C})}(C,D)$. Im newbie studying derived categories by my own and probably this is not super hard to understand but still after a week still dont know why $\mathcal{C}$ is a full subcategory of the bounded derived category $D^{b}(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: This is theorem 7.4.5 of the linked lecture notes.

Comment: The theorem gives an isomorphism $H_{0} R Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \cong Hom_{D(\mathcal{C})}(X,Y)$ but I dont see how  $H_{0} R Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ is equal or equivalent to $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$? Also the result needs more hypothesis, we need to the abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ to have enough injectives :/ @Roland

Comment: Yes sorry you are right that the theorem require an additional assumption. However, $H^0RHom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)=Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ is indeed true, and more generally, for any left exact functor $F$, we have $H^0RF(X)=F(X)$.

Comment: Yes $H^{0}R Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)=Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ but I need $H^{0}R Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)=Hom_{\mathcal{D(\mathcal{C})}}(X,Y)$ :/

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, this is exactly the theorem 7.4.5 isn't it ? (I mean if $\mathcal{C}$ has enough injectives, I haven't think about how to prove this without enough injectives)

Comment: Yes, my fault. Already undersand you, Is there any book where I can check $H^{0}RHom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)= Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) $? @Roland