# Derived $\mathrm{Hom}$-functors commute with finite direct products?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{R}_X$ be a sheaf of (commutative) rings on a topological space $X$. Let $\mathcal{M}_X, \mathcal{N}_X, \mathcal{P}_X$ be $\mathcal{R}_X$-modules.

Do the derived $\mathrm{Hom}$-functors commute with (finite) products? Meaning, do we have an isomorphism in the derived category of $\mathcal{R}_X$-modules:

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(\mathcal{M}_X\oplus \mathcal{N}_X, \mathcal{P})\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(\mathcal{M}_X, \mathcal{P})\oplus  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(\mathcal{N}_X, \mathcal{P}_X)?$$

As far as I know the following isomorphism

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(\mathcal{M}_X, \mathcal{N}_X\oplus\mathcal{P})\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(\mathcal{M}_X, \mathcal{N}_X)\oplus \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(\mathcal{M}_X,\mathcal{P})$$

actually does exist. (see for example Lemma 33.9 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/derived.pdf). But I cannot find an explanation when the direct sum is in the first argument of the derived $\mathrm{Hom}$ functor.

Comment: Do you know why the underived $\mathrm{Hom}$ commutes with direct sums in the first argument and products in the second argument?

Comment: Yes, I do. I was not sure how to adapt the underived case to the derived case. I do not understand the meaning of the derived $\textrm{Hom}$-functor. In particular, I was not sure if it is the same as $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(-, -)$ or it is something else?

Comment: It's not. You can look it up at https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A5W.

Comment: In that case, I am changing my question by removing the R in front of the $\mathrm{Hom}$-functors.

Comment: The derived category is additive. So, the above isomorphisms are true if and only if the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{D}(\mathcal{R}_X)}(-, -)$ is additive in both arguments. But I think that is true by definition of the $\mathrm{Hom}$-functor, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Although taking morphisms between sheaves in the derived category is not interesting, it's just the same as taking morphisms in the abelian category of sheaves.

Comment: I disagree. Morphisms in the derived category are zig-zag maps. They are by no means the same as morphisms in the abelian category. It is true that morphisms in the abelian categories are embedded in the derived category but not every map in the derived category stems from a map in the abelian category.

Comment: An abelian category embeds into its derived category as a full subcategory. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937655/an-abelian-category-mathcalc-is-a-full-subcategory-of-the-bounded-derived-c